# Sprite not showing when using BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have the following code outline:

Resources:

```
mMenuTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(pActivity.getTextureManager(), 2048, 2048);
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath(GFX_BASE_LOCATION);
mPlayBtnTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mMenuTextureAtlas, mActivity, "play_btn.png");
mExitBtnTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mMenuTextureAtlas, mActivity, "exit_btn.png");
mBackgroundTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mMenuTextureAtlas, mActivity, "menu_background.png");
```

Build and load:

```
try {
    mMenuTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
    mMenuTextureAtlas.load();
} catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
    Debug.e(e);
}
```

Sprites definitions:

```
mBackgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, 800, 480, mBackgroundTextureRegion, mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
mPlayBtnSprite = new Sprite(50, 100, 160, 80, mPlayBtnTextureRegion, mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
mExitBtnSprite = new Sprite(50, 200, 160, 80, mExitBtnTextureRegion, mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Attach sprites to scene:

```
mScene.attachChild(mPlayBtnSprite);
mScene.attachChild(mExitBtnSprite);
mScene.attachChild(mBackgroundSprite);
```

I've seen the above outline in countless examples but for some reason my button sprites (`mPlayBtnSprite` `mExitBtnSprite`) aren't showing on the scene. The background sprite (`mBackgroundSprite`) shows fine. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

**Update - Adding description of different situations**

1. This is what the menu scene looks like before any changes (no button sprites!):
   [image]
2. This is what the scene looks like if mBackgroundSprite is not attached (notice there are rectagles where the sprites should be, but instead of having their respective images, they are the color of the background):
   [image]
3. This is what the scene looks like if the button's TextureRegions are on a separate BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas (Both buttons are the same, although their TextureRegions are loaded with different images. The first TextureRegion to be created is the one that is shown in both buttons...!?):
   [image]
4. Adding a BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas for every sprite does indeed work, so does this mean I need a BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas for every sprite? How come it isn't needed in the [tutorials](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-6.html) I've seen?:
   [image]

Comment: No you don't have to, I honestly can't understand why you are having this behaviour because your code is correct. A hint, I don't use BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas, instead I use TexturePacks, TexturePackLoaders, TexturePackTextureRegionLibrary, etc... The texture files are created with TexturePacker. It's more efficient and easy to implement. Google it, you'll find great tutorials ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure this out: In my code I was actually creating the `Sprites` before loading the `TextureAtlas`. In other words,

```
mBackgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, 800, 480, mBackgroundTextureRegion, mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
mPlayBtnSprite = new Sprite(50, 100, 160, 80, mPlayBtnTextureRegion, mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
mExitBtnSprite = new Sprite(50, 200, 160, 80, mExitBtnTextureRegion, mActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

was called before

```
try {
    mMenuTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
    mMenuTextureAtlas.load();
} catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
    Debug.e(e);
}
```

was executed.

This was causing the unexpected behavior. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The `attachChild` order matters, so if the background fills the entire screen the mExitBtnSprite and mPlayBtnSprite are hidden behind it. Try this:

```
mScene.attachChild(mBackgroundSprite);
mScene.attachChild(mPlayBtnSprite);
mScene.attachChild(mExitBtnSprite);
```

or you can also do something like:

```
mPlayBtnSprite.setZIndex(1);
mExitBtnSprite.setZIndex(1);
mBackgroundSprite.setZIndex(0);
mScene.sortChildren(true);
```

**EDIT:**

try this:

```
mMenuTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(pActivity.getTextureManager(), 2048, 2048, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

texture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mMenuTextureAtlas, mActivity.getAssets(), "name.png");
```

or

```
atlasA = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(pActivity.getTextureManager(), imageAWidth, imageAHeight, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
atlasB = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(pActivity.getTextureManager(), imageBWidth, imageBHeight, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
atlasC = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(pActivity.getTextureManager(), imageCWidth, imageCHeight, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

textureA = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlasA, mActivity.getAssets(), "imageA.png");
textureB = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlasB, mActivity.getAssets(), "imageB.png");
textureC = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlasC, mActivity.getAssets(), "imageC.png");

atlasA.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
atlasB.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
atlasC.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));

atlasA.load();
atlasB.load();
atlasC.load();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately I tried that, as well as attaching the button sprites to the background sprite (instead of attaching to the scene) but got the same result, i.e., only the background image appears. 
I also tried creating a separate BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas for the buttons but then I got a duplicate of the first button that was created instead of two different buttons... Very strange. I'm completely lost. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't attach the mBackgroundSprite both mPlay and mExit show up or they never show up no matter what?

Comment: If I don't attach the mBackgroundSprite both mPlay and mExit do not show up, but I see two rectangles where they should be. The strange thing is, those two rectangles are not the images they should be (play_btn.png and exit_btn.png), but rather are the color of the background image (!!!), i.e., menu_background.png, as though they are showing part of the background...!?

Comment: Can you edit your question and update it with 2 screenshots showing the two case scenarios?

Comment: Iv'e added the requested screenshots. Thanks again.